# selectone in mybatis throws nullpointerException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, mybatis

DAO

```
// Review Total Count
public int reviewTotalCnt() {
    System.out.println("========== Review Total Count DAO ==========");

    return sqlSession.selectOne("ReviewMapper.reviewTotalCnt");
}
```

XML

```
<!-- Review Total Count -->
<select id="reviewTotalCnt" resultType="int">
    SELECT COUNT(r_id)
    FROM b_review;
</select>
```

Please help

I tried changing the XML resultType to Integer and the return type to Integer, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure `sqlSession` is not `null`?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.spring.ex.dao.ReviewDAO.reviewTotalCnt(ReviewDAO.java:50)

Comment: That does not answer my question. Add `if (sqlSession == null) { throw new RuntimeException("sqlSession is null");}` before calling `selectOne()` and see what happens.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: sqlSession is null
 com.spring.ex.dao.ReviewDAO.reviewTotalCnt(ReviewDAO.java:56) But in other DAO it works fine.

Comment: Oh, I didn't use @Autowired. I'm sorry..

Comment: It's alright. :)